# "import numpy" tries to load my own package

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, python-import

I have a python (2.7) project containing my own packages *util* and *operator* (and so forth).

I read about [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports), but perhaps I didn't understand. I have the following directory structure:

```
top-dir/
  util/__init__.py (empty)
  util/ua.py
  util/ub.py
  operator/__init__.py 
   ...

  test/test1.py
```

The `test1.py` file contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from __future__ import absolute_import # removing this line dosn't change anything. It's default functionality in python2.7 I guess
import numpy as np
```

It's fine when I execute `test1.py` **inside** the `test/` folder. But when I move to the `top-dir/` the `import numpy` wants to include my own `util` package:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/laplace_2d_square.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import Tester
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .result import TestResult
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/result.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import util
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 9, in <module>
    from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter, eq as _eq
ImportError: cannot import name itemgetter
```

The troublesome line is either

```
    from . import util
```

or perhaps

```
    from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter, eq as _eq
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

[operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) is a module within the Python standard library. Giving a module of yours the same name as a standard module calls for trouble, and should be avoided.

If you absolutely need a way to get around this, you could try playing with the `sys.path` variable. The first element is usually the directory of the script, or the empty string which directs the import system to the current directory.

```
oldpath = sys.path.pop(0)
import numpy
sys.path.insert(0, oldpath)
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. It's unfortunate that they made an effort to implement relative paths and then something like this cannot be avoided.